# check if file exist and wait for a sh script to run until the file is found

Tags: linux, bash

I'm working on a linux server which is sometimes very slow. So when i add some jobs to run for me i have to wait for a few hours just to run a simple calculation.

I was wondering if i am able to start the next analysis but let it wait until the output of the previous analysis is there. (the second analysis needs the first analysis output)

I tried to make except and other options working but still no success (found except and other options in previous question on stackoverflow):
`expect {
'output/analysis_file1.txt'
}`

Any ideas/hints are appreciated and will help me allot.

The only thing i want is to let the second scrip wait till the text file of the first script is given.

The 4 scripts:1.

```
#!/bin/bash
#$ -cwd
./script1.sh 

. ./script2.sh $repla

. ./script3.sh $replac
```

2:

```
repla=''
for i in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrst'
do
   repla=`echo $i | sed 's/'abc'/'xyz'/g'`
   #echo $repla
done
```

3:

```
replac=''
for j in $1
do
   replac=`echo $j | sed 's/'xyz'/'san'/g'`
   #echo $replac
done
```

4:

```
replace=''
for h in $1
do
   replace=`echo $h | sed 's/'san'/'sander'/g'`
   #echo $replace
done
```

Comment: Does the first script end when the file is complete, or does it continue on doing something else?

Comment: @William iT ends when file is complete

Comment: Then you can just chain them together on the command line: `script1 && script2` Script2 will then run when script1 is done AND returns success (0). If you don't trust the exit value of script1 to indicate success or failure, then just use `script1 ; script2` and, hopefully, script2 will do something graceful when the file isn't there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `wait` if you know the pid of the process running in background. Wait will also return the same exit code of the process it is waiting to stop.

```
firstProcess &  # Running in background
firstPid=$!
otherProcess    # Concurrent with firstProcess
wait $firstPid  # Wait firstProcess finish
anotherProcess
```

Answer (score 7):

you can use below core with some modifications

```
#!/bin/bash
while  [  ! -f FILE_NAME ]
  do
     sleep SOME_SECONDS
  done
echo "file found"
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of executing multiple scripts independently you should create a `master script runner` like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# sanity checks & parse arguments

./script1
ret=$?
# check for return value of script1 using $ret variable

./script2
ret=$?
# check for return value of script2 using $ret variable

./script3
ret=$?
# check for return value of script3 using $ret variable

...
# do cleanup and reporting
```

Comment: sorry for late 2nd question, but how can i check for a value of the last script to run the next. Something like 
`./script
wait(script)
./script2`
./script1

Comment: @SanderVanderZeeuw: You can use variable `$?` as the status of last script's execution.

Comment: Sorry, i dont exaclty understand it. Can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: Thanks, ill try this tomorrow have to go now. Ill contact you if it works for my scripts!

Comment: Sure, pls leave a comment if you have further questions.

Comment: I still cant manage to fix the scripts together. I am trying to run a for loop and the results of that for loop should be passed onto the next for loop ( in other test script ) and so on. Just to see how this connecting of scripts works. The for loop is like this: `for i in 'abcdefghijkklmnop'; do replac= echo i | 'sed s/'abc'/'xyz'g'; done`

Comment: ok, but what is result of of that for loop that you want to pass on to next script?

Comment: Ooh sorry for not describing that. the $replac should be passed to the next

Comment: Then you can pass `$replac` to other script as `./script2.sh $replac` and inside `script2.sh` just get it as `$1`.

Comment: I tried to make 3 simple scripts but still aint able to produce a output. My scripts are like this:
`#!/bin/bash
#$ -cwd
./script1.sh 
ret=$?
./script2.sh $repla
ret=$?
./script3.sh $replac
ret=$?`

`#!/bin/bash
#$ -cwd

for i in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrst'
do repla=`echo $i | sed 's/'abc'/'xyz'/g'`
echo $repla
done
`
`#!/bin/bash
#$ -cwd

for j in $1
do replac=`echo $j | sed 's/'xyz'/'san'/g'`
echo $replac
done`

Comment: @SanderVanderZeeuw: Its difficult to read script from your comment. Can you pls post your script in your question pls.

Comment: i Tried to put the scripts in my question altough something went wrong with formatting. The enumaration from 1-4 will show which script is what!

Comment: @SanderVanderZeeuw: I have edited the script in your question itself to make it work. Check it now.

Comment: still produces only the output of the first script:S

Comment: Do you mean its echoing from script1 only? Make sure all other echo statements in other scripts are uncommented.

Comment: i did that but still it only prints the first output

Comment: Something is not right in your scripts. Can you post them again in your question pls.